# Atlas-like websites on specific areas of mathematics

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, big-list, online-resources, math-communication

In this post, we look for the existing atlas-like websites providing well-presented classifications or database about some specific areas of mathematics. Here are some examples:

- GroupNames: https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames

> Finite groups of order ≤500, group names, extensions, presentations,
>   properties and character tables.

- Atlas of Finite Group Representations: http://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/v3/

> This ATLAS of Group Representations has been prepared by Robert
>   Wilson, Peter Walsh, Jonathan Tripp, Ibrahim Suleiman, Richard Parker,
>   Simon Norton, Simon Nickerson, Steve Linton, John Bray, and Rachel
>   Abbott (in reverse alphabetical order, because I'm fed up with always
>   being last!).   It currently contains information (including 5215
>   representations) on about 716 groups [mainly finite simple groups or almost simple].

- Atlas of subgroup lattice of finite almost simple groups: http://homepages.ulb.ac.be/~dleemans/atlaslat/

> This atlas contains all subgroup lattices of almost simple groups $G$
>   such that  $S≤G≤Aut(S)$ and $S$ is a simple group of order less than 1
>   million appearing in the Atlas of Finite Groups by Conway et al. Some
>   simple groups and almost simple groups or order larger than 1 million
>   have also been included, but not in a systematic way.

- The L-functions and Modular Forms Database: https://www.lmfdb.org/

> Welcome to the LMFDB, the database of L-functions, modular forms, and
>   related objects. These pages are intended to be a modern handbook
>   including tables, formulas, links, and references for L-functions and
>   their underlying objects [like field extensions and polynomial Galois groups].

- The Inverse Symbolic Calculator:  https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/

> The Inverse Symbolic Calculator (ISC) uses a combination of lookup
>   tables and integer relation algorithms in order to associate a closed
>   form representation with a user-defined, truncated decimal expansion
>   (written as a floating point expression). The lookup tables include a
>   substantial data set compiled by S. Plouffe both before and during his
>   period as an employee at CECM.

If you know such a website on any area of mathematics, please put it as an answer (with a short description).

Comment: You might be interested in Bridget Tenner's talk [Fingerprinting Richard Stanley](https://math.mit.edu/conferences/stanley70/Site/Slides/Tenner.pdf).

Comment: Also in the Notices article "Fingerprint Databases for Theorems" by Tenner and Billey.

Comment: @RussWoodroofe's reference: [Billey and Tenner - Fingerprint databases for theorems](https://www.ams.org/notices/201308/rnoti-p1034.pdf) (why reverse the author names?).

Comment: An Atlas of Even Primes would fill a much-needed gap in the literature.

Comment: @GerryMyerson:  https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EvenPrime.html

Comment: @LSpice, I think I put Tenner first because I was replying to Timothy Chow's comment on Tenner's talk.  (But you're right, I should've used the canonical order.)

Comment: The ISC is mentioned as a prime example of this.  I would be interested in a currently operating version of the ISC.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This [catalogue of mathematical datasets](https://mathdb.mathhub.info/) could be of some interest to you - at least some of the entries are atlas-like websites. It includes several of the websites mentioned above, and I'm slowly adding more to it.

Comment: Although mere thanks in comments are discouraged, I cannot resist: very, very useful work, thank you very much for your initiative and effort!

Comment: It seems OP is not only collecting datasets but also [working](https://data.mathhub.info/) to [standarize](https://imkt.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/slides-bercic.pdf) them, great work!

Answer (score 44):

A classic: [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (OEIS)](http://oeis.org/).

Comment: I'd be very surprised if anyone here hasn't heard of this

Comment: @BlueRaja https://xkcd.com/1053/

Comment: I'm one of the lucky people today <3

Answer (score 33):

- [Atlas of Lie Groups and Representations](http://www.liegroups.org/): info on [lie groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_simple_Lie_groups), there is a nice [article](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/math-has-no-god-particle/) on the history of this atlas
- [Atlas of Finite Group Representations](http://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/v3/): info on [finite groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_finite_simple_groups) actually the succesor of a [book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATLAS_of_Finite_Groups) (already mentioned by OP but added it anyway to keep it symmetric with the first point)
- [Complexity zoo](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo):list of [complexity classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_complexity_classes) and what is know about them
- [Quantum algorithm zoo](https://quantumalgorithmzoo.org): list of [quantum algorithms](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Quantum_algorithms)
- [Knot Atlas](http://katlas.org/wiki/Main_Page): list of [knots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_knots)
- [Encyclopedia of triangles center](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html): list of triangle [centers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encyclopedia_of_Triangle_Centers)
- [Bilbao chrystallographic server](https://www.cryst.ehu.es/): list of [space groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_space_groups) and info although more physics oriented
- [Cantor's Attic](http://cantorsattic.info): A wiki about large cardinal axioms, large countable ordinals, and infinity in general
- [Googology wiki](https://googology.wikia.org/wiki/Googology_Wiki): Info on [googology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_numbers)
- [Digital Library of Mathematical Functions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/): a spiritual successor to a [book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Library_of_Mathematical_Functions) too and there is also a nice [article](http://www.ams.org/notices/201107/rtx110700905p.pdf) on the history

Comment: https://math.la.asu.edu/~jj/localfields/

Comment: https://polytope.miraheze.org/wiki/Main_Page

Comment: https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/

Comment: https://www.2dcurves.com/

Comment: Does this also count as an atlas page? http://log.chez.com/text/logic/links_ordinals.html

Comment: @C7X I wouldn't call it an atlas page but I wouldn't say either that it less useful because it isn't, feel free to add it to the answer if you want, I have left some other pages as comment not because a particular criteria but only because while I want to mention them at the same time I want to avoid appearing in the feed of active answers.

Comment: https://errorcorrectionzoo.org/

Answer (score 21):

Here's another one.

- The Manifold Atlas Project: http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Main_Page

Answer (score 20):

[Forking and dividing](http://forkinganddividing.com) is a map of the model theory universe, visually classifying some 63 first-order theories.

Answer (score 17):

[PolyDB](https://db.polymake.org/) is a database of polytopes. It can either be accessed through the website or directly from [polymake](https://polymake.org/doku.php).

Answer (score 16):

Another one is the [Catalogue of Lattices](http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/%7EGabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/).

> This data-base of lattices is a joint project of Gabriele Nebe, RWTH Aachen university (nebe(AT)math.rwth-aachen.de) and Neil Sloane. (njasloane(AT)gmail.com).
>
> Our aim is to give information about all the interesting lattices in "low" dimensions (and to provide them with a "home page"!). The data-base now contains about 160,000 lattices!

Answer (score 16):

I am trying to keep up with the area of symmetric functions, and various generalizations:
[The symmetric functions catalog](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~peal/polynomials/polynomialindex.htm)

Answer (score 15):

The Information System on Graph Classes and their Inclusions:
http://www.graphclasses.org/

This is a database of graph classes with a java application that helps you to research what's known about particular graph classes.

Answer (score 14):

[$\pi$-base](https://topology.pi-base.org/) has examples of topological spaces and their properties.

Comment: Here are two more on general topology:  http://hyperspacewiki.org/index.php/Main_Page https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Main_Page

Answer (score 13):

The graded rings database

http://www.grdb.co.uk

A database of varieties (toric varieties, Fano varieties, Calabi-Yaus).

Answer (score 11):

Here is a [database of Vertex Operator Algebras and Modular Categories](https://www.math.ksu.edu/~gerald/voas/), though it is still in an early version.

Answer (score 11):

The [Blocks of Finite Groups](https://wiki.manchester.ac.uk/blocks/index.php/Main_Page) wiki, which aims to classify the Morita equivalence classes of blocks with a given defect group. This is in part to understand [Donovan's Conjecture](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.08152.pdf) better.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe not exactly an "atlas", but there is a classification of some certain types of PDEs studied in analysis at

- The Dispersive PDE Wiki: https://kvm16.pims.math.ca/DispersiveWiki/index.php?title=Main_Page
- WikiWaves: https://wikiwaves.org/

Answer (score 10):

The [Database of Ring Theory (and Module Examples)](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com) features

1. over 100 examples of rings
2. tracking of over 100 different ring theoretic properties each can have.
3. Information on important subsets (i.e. zero divisors, Jacobson radical)
4. notions of dimension (composition length, Krull dimension, etc.)
5. Links to articles and/or books for each ring and property
6. Properties about the properties (being Morita invariant, passing to polynomial rings, etc.)
7. Sundry information about ring theory and theorems, errata in literature, diagrams of implications

I always welcome suggestions for additions: there is too much work for one person to do.

### Update

The site now tracks examples of modules over the rings, too. Not all of the features tracked above are fully supported yet but that is the plan.

Answer (score 7):

A classic by Stanisław Radiszowski:

= = = = = = **Small Ramsey Numbers** = = = = = =

https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/DS1/pdf

Last update on 2017-03-03. All known Ramsey numbers or their estimates are provided for several different types of graphs and colorings.

Answer (score 7):

There's the [Reverse Math Zoo](https://rmzoo.math.uconn.edu/).

Answer (score 7):

[Pieter Belmans](https://pbelmans.ncag.info/) at the University of Bonn maintains a couple of such websites.

There is **[Fanography](https://fanography.pythonanywhere.com/)**, "a tool to visually study the geography of Fano 3-folds."

And **[le superficie algebriche](https://superficie.info/)**, "a tool for studying numerical invariants of minimal algebraic surfaces over the complex numbers". [Johan Commelin](https://math.commelin.net/) also contributed to this one.

Comment: https://pbelmans.ncag.info/blog/atlas/

Answer (score 6):

[Regina](https://regina-normal.github.io) and [SnapPy](https://www.math.uic.edu/t3m/SnapPy/index.html) are free program suits for research in low-dimensional topology (particularly in dimension 3), and are accompanied by large census databases of closed 3-manifolds, knots and links. Some highlights:

- **Knot tables** up to 19 (!) crossings ([Regina](https://regina-normal.github.io/data.html#knots))
- **Closed, orientable 3-maifolds** with at most 11 tetrahedra ([Regina](https://regina-normal.github.io/data.html#census))
- Knots **and links** with up to 14 crossings ([SnapPy](https://www.math.uic.edu/t3m/SnapPy/censuses.html))
- Various censuses of **hyperbolic 3-manifolds** ([Regina](https://regina-normal.github.io/data.html#census), [SnapPy](https://www.math.uic.edu/t3m/SnapPy/censuses.html))

Answer (score 5):

[The Cunningham Project](https://homes.cerias.purdue.edu/~ssw/cun/) seeks to factor the numbers $b^n \pm 1$ for
$b = 2$, $3$, $5$, $6$, $7$, $10$, $11$, $12$, up to high powers $n$.

Comment: (No relation.)​

Answer (score 5):

KnotInfo https://knotinfo.math.indiana.edu/

LinkInfo https://linkinfo.math.indiana.edu/

These are databases of all knots and links up to a certain number of crossings, along with many different computed invariants and properties.

Answer (score 5):

[The Atlas of Small Regular Polytopes](http://atlas.dr-mikes-maths.com/atlas/index.html) (Michael Hartley) "contains information about all regular polytopes with $n$ flags where $n$ is at most 2000, and not equal to 1024 or 1536".

The website of [Dimitri Leemans](http://homepages.ulb.ac.be/~dleemans/index.html) has

- [An Atlas of Abstract Regular Polytopes for Small Almost Simple Groups](http://homepages.ulb.ac.be/~dleemans/polytopes/index.html)
- [An Atlas of Chiral Polytopes for Small Almost Simple Groups](http://homepages.ulb.ac.be/~dleemans/CHIRAL/index.html)
- [An atlas of subgroup lattices of finite almost simple groups](http://homepages.ulb.ac.be/~dleemans/atlaslat/)

The website of [Marston Conder](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~conder/) has many catalogs of information related to maps, hypermaps, polytopes, symmetric graphs, and surface actions.

[Combinatorial Data](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/graphs.html) (Brendan McKay) has complete collections of various classes of graph, up to some number of vertices, in [graph6](http://staffhome.ecm.uwa.edu.au/~00013890/g6.html) format.

[Combinatorial Catalogues](http://school.maths.uwa.edu.au/~gordon/data.html) (Gordon Royle) has class 2 graphs up to 9 vertices, trees up to 16, bipartite up to 14, 3-regular up to 22, and more.

[Regular Graphs](http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/markus/reggraphs.html) (M. Meringer) has information and shortcode files for "simple connected $k$-regular graphs on $n$ vertices and girth at least $g$ with given parameters $n,k,g$."

[The House of Graphs](https://hog.grinvin.org/) is a searchable "Database of interesting graphs".

Answer (score 5):

There is a [database of matroids](http://www-imai.is.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~ymatsu/matroid/). For example, it includes a list of all $4,886,380,924$ isomorphism classes of matroids of rank 4 on 10 elements!

Answer (score 4):

If you are interested in historical things,

[John Jones' number fields database](https://hobbes.la.asu.edu/NFDB/)

and

[William Stein's modular forms database](https://www.wstein.org/Tables/) (which also includes elliptic curve data, such as the Cremona database) used to be standard such websites.  Now this information is subsumed into the

[L-functions and modular forms database (LMFDB)](https://www.lmfdb.org/)

mentioned by the OP.

Answer (score 4):

[A database of number fields](http://galoisdb.math.upb.de/home), by Jürgen Klüners and Gunter Malle. (Note this is not the same as the one mentioned in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/354377/6085).)

The site also provides links to similar databases.

Answer (score 3):

Another classic, this time about prime numbers, it provides some theoretical results and a lot of data:

= = = = = = https://primes.utm.edu/ = = = = = =

There are many more pages and portals devoted to elementary number theory.

Answer (score 3):

**Enumerating Order Types for Small Point Sets with Applications**

- [Database](http://www.ist.tugraz.at/staff/aichholzer/research/rp/triangulations/ordertypes/) (maintained by Oswin Aichholzer, TU Graz)
- [Background paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A%3A1021231927255) (by O. Aichholzer, F. Auerhammer, H. Krasser (2002))

Answer (score 3):

Many Internet pages provide (or used to) lotto design tables. In particular, the following paper seems solid:

= = = Lotto Design Tables (by P. C. Li and G. H. J. van Rees),

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.5.4298&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 3):

[Table of absolutely maximally entangled states.](http://www.ametable.net)

Abbreviated as AME(n,D), the table lists quantum states of n parties with D levels each that show maximal entanglement across every bipartition. These states are equivalent to pure $((n,1,n/2+1))_D$ quantum error correcting codes, and are in the case of n even also known as perfect tensors or multi-unitary matrices. They can be seen as a type of self-dual quantum codes.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.polychora.de/wiki/images/ has renders of cross-sections, vertex figures and their duals, and cellets for many (possibly all) of the 1849 uniform polychora known at the time it was created.

Answer (score -3):

You can look at HandWiki https://handwiki.org/ too. It is a dedicated resource for mathematics

Comment: How is that different from Wikipedia? Looking at a few random articles suggests that most or all of the content has been copied from Wikipedia.